# Search in all columns in crate

Tags: cratedb

As elastic search has `_all` field I am not able to find anything regarding that in `cratedb`. SO do we need to maintain our own analyzed field for that purpose or does crate provide something in built?

Answer (score 1):

The _all field is a special catch-all field which concatenates the values of all of the other fields into one big string, using space as a delimiter, which is then analyzed and indexed, but not stored. This means that it can be searched, but not retrieved.

The _all field allows you to search for values in documents without knowing which field contains the value. This makes it a useful option when getting started with a new dataset

refer : **https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-all-field.html**

Comment: I edited question I wanted to do that in `cratedb`. I already know about es stuff

Comment: Okay. May be i misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 1):

We don't have something similar to that, so you'd need to add it to the query or maintain a dedicated column.